# How can I achieve this specific lighting/shading in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting

I'm kind of a noob when it comes to lighting, and I'd like to make renders that use one of these types of lighting/shading with a Node Setup. Nintendo tends to use this type of lighting/shading in various 3DS games.

[image: Nintendogs Hand]
[image: Streetpass Mii's]

It's like those objects and characters are shadeless (shadeless like the option in Blender Internal), but they clearly aren't?

Here's download links to both the [Hand](https://www.models-resource.com/download/15995/) and the characters' [Body](https://www.models-resource.com/download/22496/).

Comment: Sounds counter intuitive to be using a resource intensive  physically based unbiased path tracer to recreate basic cartoonish OpenGL shading

Comment: Blender internal doesn't "suck" it has its uses, one of which is probably this, which could also probably be easily be captured directly from a bare OpenGL viewport preview

Comment: This is exactly the style that comes natural to Blender Internal while on Cycles you need to disable and hack to achieve this. You should definitely make use of BI in cases like this but I'm not saying it's impossible on Cycles, just very inefficient and counter-productive.

Comment: You could probably even make it look like this in the viewport and OpenGL render in no time. Cycles is for photorealistic rendering. Doing this in Cycles is basically shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Blender internal is perfect for this stuff actually. Because the basic setup provides this look. for the hand you might want to look into Fresnel node and mix it with your color.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the shade  effect on the ball, this can be achieve by baking a new texture based on cycles rendering.

1. prepare your scene with all the expected lighting from the game. This is important because if your blender lighting is too different from the game, the shadows etc will look off. Obviously to match the NDS look, try to keep the lighting very simple light a single sun.
2. select the target object and unwrap the normals or select a specific normal projection
3. create a new target texture image in nodes and select it
4. Use the bake feature to render the object onto the target texture

Note: you can also bake only the shadow map (or emission, or glossy...) instead of the combined which you can tweak and merge as desired with your original texture in external editing software

[image]

Same concept for Blender internal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could just turn up the Ambient Occlusion option rather high and add a sun lamp for a bit of added overall direction. This should result in something similar to what you're looking for.